# JAVA Metodo con parametro objeto

Tags: java

En el ejercicio que continuamos con la clase teatro, nos piden ahora hacer dos métodos traspasar obra con el parámetro objeto Teatro. No nos han explicado como hacer, que poner en el parámetro a la hora de hacer el metodo... pongo el enunciado y lo que llevo, muchas gracias y un saludo.

- Para representar el proceso de traspaso de la obra de teatro que se está representando a otro teatro habrá que implementar el método traspasarObra, que recibirá como parámetro  un objeto de tipo Teatro, que será el teatro al que se quiera traspasar la obra del teatro actual.
  Lo primero que tendremos en cuenta es que no se puede traspasar la obra si el teatro no tiene ninguna asignada. En caso de que se intentara, debería lanzarse una excepción del tipo IllegalStateException con el siguiente mensaje de error "El teatro actual no tiene una obra asignada, no puede traspasarse".

Tampoco podrá traspasarse si el teatro destino tiene ya una obra asignada. En caso de que se intentara, debería lanzarse una excepción del tipo IllegalStateException con el siguiente mensaje de error "El teatro de respaldo tiene ya una obra asignada, no puede traspasarse".

De igual modo, si las entradas vendidas para la obra que se desea traspasar supera el aforo del teatro destino tampoco podrá traspasarse. En caso de que se intentara, debería lanzarse una excepción del tipo IllegalStateException con el siguiente mensaje de error "Se supera el aforo del teatro de respaldo, no se puede realizar el traspaso".

Recuerda que si el objeto que pasamos como parámetro es nulo se produciría una excepción de tipo NullPointerException, que deberíamos controlar lanzando la excepción con el mensaje "El teatro al que se está intentando traspasar la obra no existe" .

Si se puede realizar el traspaso, se deberán actualizar los atributos correspondientes del teatro nuevo con los valores del teatro actual, así como reiniciar los atributos correspondientes del teatro actual.

Y lo que llevo de código es

```
public class Teatro {

//Atributos de clase
// -----------------------


//Atributos de clase constantes

public final static int AFORO_MAX = 1000;        // Aforo maximo permitido en un teatro
public final static int AFORO_MIN = 300;         //Aforo minimo permitido en un teatro
public final static int DEFAULT_AFORO = 800;     //Aforo por defecto en un teatro




//Atributos de clase variables (representan informacion de la clase)

private static int NumeroTeatros = 0;                         //Numero de teatros instanciados
private static int CantidadObras= 0;                         //Cantidad total de obras activas que se estan representando
private static int EntradasVendidasTotales = 0;              //Cantidad de entradas vendidas en todos los teatros y todas las funciones
private static int CodigoActual =0;                        ////Esto es una variable estatica es comun para todas las instancias de la clase teatro
private int ObrasActuales =0; 


//Atributos de objeto
// -----------------------


// Atributos de objeto constantes (representan características inmutables)
private int codigoTeatro;                         // Codigo del teatro
private String nombreTeatro;                         // Nombre del teatro    
private int aforo;                                // Aforo del teatro


// Atributos de objeto variable (representan el estado)
   
private static String Obra;                                       // Obra que se está representando
private int EntradasVendidas =0 ;                           // Numero de entradas vendidas
public int Codigo = 0;
public int Teatros= 0;
public int Entradas = 0;
public String nuevoTeatro;

//Constructor de dos parametros (nombre y aforo)


public Teatro (String Nombre, int Aforo) throws IllegalArgumentException, NullPointerException {  //Constructor 1
    
    //Comprobacion de que los valores son correctos
    
    if (Nombre == null)        //Comprobacion de que el nombre no es null
        throw new NullPointerException ( "El nombre del teatro no puede ser nulo.");
    if (Nombre == "")           //Comprobacion de que no es una cadena vacia
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("El nombre del teatro no puede ser una cadena vacia.");
    if (Aforo>1000 || Aforo<300)            //Comprobacion aforo maximo teatro
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "Aforo incorrecto: " + Aforo);
    
    
    // Una vez que los valores son correctos, podemos instanciar el objeto)
    
    this.nombreTeatro = Nombre;
    this.aforo = Aforo;
    
    
    //Asignacion de valores iniciales a los atributos de estado (variables)
    
    this.Obra= null;
    this.Codigo = ++ CodigoActual;
    this.Teatros= ++ NumeroTeatros;
    this.ObrasActuales = ++CantidadObras;
    
    
}

    
public Teatro (String Nombre) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
    
    this(Nombre, Teatro.DEFAULT_AFORO);
    
} 
   



public Teatro (){
       this ("Teatro" , Teatro.DEFAULT_AFORO);
       
   }

    public void traspasarObra (Teatro teatroNuevo) throws IllegalArgumentException{
       
       if (!teatroNuevo.contains(Obra)){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro actual no tiene una obra asignada, no puede traspasarse");}
       
   }
```

Comment: Llevas varias preguntas, donde no estas pudiendo hacer el ejercicio que te mandan. Basicamente, el sitio puede bloquearte si tus preguntas siguen recibiendo negativos. Si tenes tantos problemas con el ejercicio, la recomendacion es que hables con el profesor. Lo que llevas, no es nada.. donde esta tu problema concreto? "hacer dos métodos traspasar obra con el parámetro objeto Teatro." no es un problema concreto.. es mas, ni se entiende que es....

Comment: @gbianchi es un grado superior a distancia, los profesores no están, solo reciben las tareas y las corrigen, no se les puede preguntar las dudas. Con respecto al problema es el poner un parámetro objeto que es Teatro para ver si tiene asignada una obra o no, cuando no se como poner como parámetro dicho objeto. Disculpa si molesto, pero no se como hacerlo si no, ni donde poder preguntar. Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: Algo como `nombreMetodo(Teatro teatro) { ... }`. Luego, lo que hagas con la variable `teatro` dentro de `nombreMetodo` es otro asunto.

Comment: No molestas.. pero no estas consiguiendo respuestas, estamos haciendo practicamente todo el ejercicio por vos, y no estas entendiendo los conceptos, que es la idea de hacer un curso. Podemos resolver todo, pero creo que deberias seguir varios tutoriales que te expliquen los conceptos de lo que tratas de hacer.

Comment: @MauricioContreras es que lo tiene en su codigo `public void traspasarObra (Teatro teatroNuevo)`... pero realmente no entiende lo que tiene... es mas profundo el problema... Te van a dar soluciones de codigo, pero no vas a entender para que sirve...

Comment: @antonio... bien, pasaste el objeto como se debe pasar, solo implementa las demas verificaciones... ya lo tienes!!!!

Comment: Creo que lo lógico, sería que el método traspasar, estubiese ubicado en la clase auxiliar, ya que involucra a dos teatros... o tal vez nop.

Comment: @MarcePuente Si, lo que no se es que parámetro poner para que hacer la comparación... es decir he creado la variable teatro nuevo para ponerlo pero no se con que lo pongo if(teatroNuevo..... muchas gracias y un saludo. Con vuestras explicaciones no me estáis haciendo el código, sino enseñado y así yo aprendo.

Comment: @gbianchi voy entendiendo sobre lo voy haciendo... lo que me cuesta son varios conceptos que no explican en el temario y por eso pregunto, porque al hacerlo como ustedes decís, voy aprendiendo. La duda es que ya tengo la variable creada fuera nuevoTeatro, pero no se dentro en if( nuevoTeatro... con que compararlo, porque me da error por static. Muchas gracia sy un saludo

Comment: @antonio, para entender este método, tienes que tener en cuenta, que hay 2 teatros,.. el local, al que haces referencia con **this**, y el que recibes como parámetro, al que simplemente te refieres como **teatroNuevo**, yo me equivoque, la primera comprobación está mal, se debe comprobar sobre **this** que es el teatro local, y no sobre **teatroNuevo**, que es al que va a ir la obra.

Comment: No estás haciendo nada que no hayas hecho antes, es fácil equivocarse, ya lo ves, yo me equivoqué, hay que leer y releer el enunciado... y resolver lo que te piden.

Comment: Cuando le pides datos a **nuevoTeatro**, recurre a los geters... **String tituloObra = nuevoTeatro.getObra();**

Comment: @MarcePuente Es que no entiendo de pedirle daros a nuevoTeatro. Y recurriendo a los get estás cogiendo que el títuloObra le des el valor de tener obra al nuevo teatro, pero eso como lo hago con los if?

Comment: "Lo primero que tendremos en cuenta es que no se puede traspasar la obra si el teatro no tiene ninguna asignada" -> primer paso, verificar que el teatro local, tenga una obra asignada, "Tampoco podrá traspasarse si el teatro destino tiene ya una obra asignada" -> segundo paso, verificar que teatroNuevo **no** tenga una obra asignada, "si las entradas vendidas para la obra que se desea traspasar supera el aforo del teatro destino tampoco podrá traspasarse" -> verificar entradasVendidas < teatroNuevo.getAforo();... "... etc.

Comment: Las respuestas van **en la zona de respuestas**, no como edición a tu pregunta. Es por eso que tu edición fue revertida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona:

```
if( EntradasVendidas > teatroNuevo.getAforo() ) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(  blablabla );
}
```

Aca tenemos variables de ambos teatros en juego, cuando escribo **EntradasVendidas**, estoy haciendo referencia al teatro local (al que se le quita la obra), y con **teatroNuevo.getAforo()** le pregunto al otro teatro, cual es su capacidad (si el método **getAforo()** no existe, debes implementarlo), solo te resta implementar las demás verificaciones.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo que me faltaba era saber comprender el ejercicio... te lo comparto aquí, muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Grande @antonio, eso si, fijate que **! teatroNuevo.tieneObra()** está negando, que lleva al comportamiento contrario al esperado... sabía que ibas a poder!!